# Which user's data must not be taken from a user using my app?

Tags: android, ios

My app has a special reporting feature. So when a user wants to report something via my app, which user's and phone's data I **must not take and send** to my web service?

The data I am referring to ranges from Contacts to phone's unique ID, etc.

I need these regulations for Android and iOS as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of the thumb, you should never send personal data like email IDs, locations, contacts, messages etc. unless you absolutely have to. And if you do have to, you should explicitly take the user's permission before doing so, by showing a dialog or something. Simply putting a line like `this app may access and store personal data remotely` in your description is usually not enough, as a good amount of people never read the description fully.

On the other hand, phone IDs like IMEIs and MAC addresses are pretty standard identification techniques, and are used by ad networks etc. anyways, so you generally don't need to bother telling the user about their collection explicitly.

Comment: BTW Amazon once rejected our app as we were using some Ad service which sent user's phone number (or some data like this) to their web service.

Comment: Ad services usually take the READ_PHONE_STATE permission to access device IDs like the IMEI so that they can figure out which device clicked what ad on their end. I haven't heard of any of them collecting phone numbers.

Comment: Hm.. I could not find that ad service. Could it be Moolah ads...? not sure. Some ads which did not have JAR file but raw classes. Anyway, this phone number was obligatory in ads class constructor. I tried adding empty string but Amazon did not let us thru.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any "regulations" you can use.  What are the regulations in Uzbekistan?  Papua New Guinea, etc.

You could use the EU regulations which are probably as advanced as any http://ec.europa.eu/justice/data-protection/index_en.htm

However, you can use an approach which I can't imagine would fall foul of any existing legislation:

- Only collect the information you need in support of your app/service.
- Tell the user what you are collecting
- Explain why you need it
- Explain how you will use and store that data
- Give the user the option to not send the data

Comment: You mean via popup before sending such data or some other simpler way? Pop-ups which need confirmation are irritating for most users

Comment: I would use a popup.  When I'm using apps, I'm actually happier that they take this approach - and you could always use "Yes, and don't ask again".